# Transactional Emails multistore

Tags: magento-1.9, transactional-mail

I have about 20 transactional emails setup for the default store. I want to be able to duplicate the emails for a few multistores I have created and assign them to be sent to customers purchasing through the multistore. I am looking for a way to duplicate the current set of emails I have created and then changing the name of the email and modifying the logo. Is there an easy way to do this or am I going to have to do this the long way?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep the content and heading of your transactional e-mails flexible you should make use of the "**insert variables**" option when compiling your e-mail template.

For instance:

```
 < td valign="top">
   < a href="{{store url=""}}">
      < img src="{{var logo_url}}" alt="{{var logo_alt}}" style="margin-bottom:10px;"
 border="0" width="360" height="40"/>
   < /a>
 < /td>
```

This allows you to automatically adjust the Logo that the e-mail uses for each store. It uses the logo you set in:

```
system/configuration/general/design/transactional emails/logo
```

Same goes for the heading of the email and so on. The variables available to you are fairly extensive.